# Initial Velocity Vector and Diagram from Parametric Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, parametric

I have a project where we have to throw an object and find the velocity of it. I have found the parametric equations of the path of the object to be:

$$x(t)=0.627273t+(−0.211364)$$
$$y(t)=−0.658275t^2+1.96578t+0.014545$$

I have found that the initial velocity vector is:

$$v^2 =  0.627273^2 + 1.96578^2$$
$$v = 2.06343461853$$
$$v(t) = (0.627273,1.96578)$$
Firstly, is this correct?

Secondly, we are required to make a diagram showing the initial velocity vector and the components. How am I to do this accurately on the graph (in Desmos)?

Comment: It is $v (0) $ instead of $v (t) $ just before Firstly.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial velocity vector is correct but your $v(t)$ is incorrect. It should be:

$$v(t)=(0.627273, -1.31655t+ 1.96578)$$

Yes, the velocity in the $y$ direction changes over time. At the initial time, $t=0$ and that first term in the $y$ component disappears. A true $v(t)$ is then found from these components:

$$v(t)= \sqrt{0.627273^2 + (-1.31655t+ 1.96578)^2}$$